# It is possible to edit these HTML tags in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system, elementor

I'm editing a website created with Wordpress and a template, and it looks like certain features are locked so you have to buy Elementor builder. This far, I've managed to edit all of the things that I wanted to change using additional CSS and the Elementor demo.

The thing is that there is a specific thing that I can't change unless I modify the HTML tags that (I guess that because of Bootstrap) make the column have half the width of the container. You know, the kind of col-lg-6, col-xl-6, etc.

Obviously, using Chrome browser I can change those tags to the ones I want (col-lg-12, etc.) but that's momentary. I don't know if it's possible to change those tags somehow. Any idea?

I'll leave here the screenshot so you can see the tags I'm talking about. Thanks a lot, hope you can help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap `col` can be 12 maximum. 12 column width is the maximum amount and that will be the full width of the parent. Your code says col is 5 wide on xxl (extra extra large screens), 6 wide on lg (large) screens and 8 wide on md (medium) screens. To get full width specify `col-12` and remove the rest. It will be full width on all screens.

`col-12`

^ This column is always 12 wide on all screens

`col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7`

^ This is one column but different widths depending on small, medium, large or extra large screen size with 12 being the full width for small screens in my example. That's Quite regular. You could have `col-sm-11` or  `col-sm-10` it just depends what you want it to look like.

With the above code, as the screen size gets larger the column becomes a bit slimmer. This is somwhat relative to the eye and what looks nice so don't be confused. A `col-7` looks pretty big on a very large screen with loads of room for a great background.

Comment: Let me explain myself a little bit better: the module of the template in which this is happening, it is actually a two column section. The thing is that I don't want one of those two columns. But the problem is that, deleting one of them, the other one is still one column width. I need to manually change the tags to col-lg-12, col-md-12, etc. but I don't know how can I change these tags. That was my question, indeed.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you remove one of the columns completely the remaining one will stay at the same width. You seem to be hinting that the HTML you have circled above cannot be changed manually? Your editor won't allow a hand-coded alteration? In that circled section you can (if possible) remove all of the `col` information inside the `class=` statement and just replace it all with `col-12`. I'm not quite following why the code can't be edited?

Comment: The code can't be edited because this is a Wordpress project. So the HTML code that I posted it's actually seen through Chrome browser when you right click and inspect the elements. So any change that I would do there, will be deleted as soon as I refresh the page. What I would love it's to find a way to edit the HTML tags that are created through Wordpress, but obviously, I can't edit the HTML on the backoffice, so I should probably look for the specific file which is telling that to be two columns instead of one.

Comment: I am completely inexperienced with Wordpress so apologies but hopefully somebody else can add something valuable here. Do have to say though that with Bootstrap it won't be a separate file dictating things. You do use lots of standard code with Bootstrap of course and styling but the thing which is making a half-width column with is definitely the circled part of your HTML. Actually I've learned something. I had no idea that HTML can't be manually edited in Wordpress. Kinda shocked.